# Can my wife travel with my ESTA?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I am French, but my wife is Turkish. We are both residents of the UK, where we got married.
We need to go to the USA, and I am wondering:
As my wife, can she come with a group ESTA or do we need to apply for a B visa separately?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87315/can-you-travel-individually-to-the-united-states-on-a-group-esta?rq=1 suggests that the "group ESTA" is just a convenient way to apply for several individual ESTAs at the same time, which are then processed individually.  If so, then if you try a group application, you would most likely be accepted but she would be denied.

Comment: @NateEldredge it shouldn't even be possible to add the wife to the group application because she does not have a passport from a VWP country.

Comment: what's a "group ESTA"?

Answer (score 17):

Turkey is not part of the Visa Waiver Program, so she can't travel on an ESTA. Besides, ESTA is individual, even if she were eligible, she would need her own.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and she needs a visa unless her home country is in the waiver program too.

Comment: While this sounds plausible, please include what source you used. "It happened to me" might be a starting point, but your answer would be much better if you could back it up with the reasoning WHY (e.g. - as dda wrote - the detail that Turkey is not part of the Visa Waiver Program etc.) and possibly links (e.g. to the official ESTA site that lists the country in the Visa Waiver Program)

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question of someone traveling on someone else's, or a "group", ESTA, which is not possible whether they are from a Waiver country or not.  Each Waiver traveler must have their own ESTA